# Jquery makes ajax to call on the input but keeps writing while waiting for the response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an input box. When user starts typing in, I keep checking on length of input and when it is 6, I make an AJAX call.

As soon as AJAX call is fired, user can not type further. What change I should make so that user can still continue to write while AJAX is working in background.

```
$(".myInput").on('input', function (e) {
    var value = e.target.value;

    if (value.length == 6) {
        callAjax(value);
    }
});

var callAjax= function (bin) { 
    Core.post("/url", { bin: bin }, function (result) {
        var data = JSON.parse(result.d);
        var val = data.Id +;
        console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **How i can make keep writing**? What do you want to do by ajax response?

Comment: @Mohammad when input have 6 character i call function inside this function i make ajax call to some url, while waiting to response from url i can't write more character to input when response coming then i can.. But i wan't to keep writing to input while ajax request working too.

Comment: It sounds like you've set `async: false` in your AJAX call which is blocking the UI. Remove that. You can also abort any previous requests when a new key is pressed. If you need more specific help with this, please add the content of the `callAjax()` function to the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i added to my ajax call function to question how there is no have async: false or i need to write it somewhere?

Comment: What is `Core` a reference to?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to append some response matching the inserted data by means of obtained result. So the best way to do that will be using "keyup()" function of jquery which will fire the ajax on every change in the input field. 
Or if you want to fire it regularly set time interval for the function.

Try doing something like this.

```js
$(".myInput").keyup(function(e) {
            var value = e.target.value;

            if (value.length == 6) {
                callAjax(value);
            }
        });
```